# Why can't I override #asset_path from ActionView?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on upgrading an app to Rails 5, and `#asset_path` now raises if the url is nil. I'm trying to monkey patch that method with a version that will work like Rails 4 so that I can get my tests passing.

I've spent hours on this, and I'm going crazy. For some reason no matter what I do, I can't monkey patch the module. I thought this initializer would work:

```rb
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module AssetUrlHelper
      alias asset_path_raise_on_nil asset_path

      def asset_path(source, options = {})
        return '' if source.nil?
        asset_path_raise_on_nil(source, options)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I also tried putting my method in another module and `include`ing, `prepend`ing, and `append`ing it to both `ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper` and `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`.

No matter what I do, I can't get my method to be executed. The only way I can alter the method is to `bundle open actionview` and changing the actual method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that it is because `#asset_path` is simply an alias. I needed to override the method which the alias points at:

```rb
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module AssetTagHelper
      alias_method :path_to_asset_raise_on_nil, :path_to_asset

      def path_to_asset(source, options = {})
        return '' if source.nil?
        path_to_asset_raise_on_nil(source, options)
      end
    end
  end
end
```